# To reference a custom view in java file and place all of them in a single XML layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I would like to place a custom view in the bottom of the main.xml file.following is my Activity class and my custom view class(game.java):I want the game view to appear on the bottom of the main.xml file.Please tell me how to get on with it....I think the idea is to have a layout set in main.xml and then have the custom view on the layout.My main objective is to have the custom view appear on bottom half of main.xml layout.Please help me!!!!!

//LearningActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //For my button class
    /*
    MyButton myb = (MyButton)findViewById(R.id.mybutton1);
    myb.setText("Hello Students");
    myb.setTextSize(40);
    **/

    //For custom view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout r=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    g=new game(this,null);
            ViewGroup vgroup=(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main);
     vgroup.addView(g);
    Thread mythread=new Thread(new UpdateThread());
    mythread.start();


}
```

Game.java(custom view)

```
public class game extends View{


private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private int x=0;private int baseY = 250;


public game(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);

    this.inflate(context, R.layout.example, null);
    image=Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    paint =new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

}

public View getlay (RelativeLayout r)
{
    return r;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawLine(90, baseY,200,baseY, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(125,baseY,125,baseY-100,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(110,baseY,125,baseY-15,paint);
..................

}
```

)

LOGCAT:

```
    06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{your.com.learn/your.com.learn.LearningActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class your.com.learn.game
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class your.com.learn.game
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at your.com.learn.LearningActivity.onCreate(LearningActivity.java:38)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  ... 11 more
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: game(Context,AttributeSet)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
06-28 22:43:59.757: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: following is my  main.XML files:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

Comment: example.xml   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    

</FrameLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your main.xml layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Some others widgets here -->

    <yourpackagename.Game
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and call `sentContentView(R.layout.main)`

Comment: I want the custom view to appear on bottom half of the screen.

Comment: Do we have to put onMeasure function in custom view since I am using onDraw and want it to appear in a XML layout at the bottom of the layout ?

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath you have to override onDraw and onMeasure for custom view. Can you post your logcat

Comment: Anas I added the Attribute set parameter to the game(custom view ) constructor and I added the  XMl code as you specified above.The image appears but how do I force it to appear at bottom of the main.xml file without changing the ondraw parameters....for example:canvas.drawline functions are based on the starting x and y positions,etc but aren't they dependent only on their view.

Comment: My intention is to force the custom view and its drawings  appear below the center half of the main.xml layout...If I have a view described in main.xml file and have my custom view on it will my onDraw work ?

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath yes you will get your custom view drown, just use attribute sush
android:layout_gravity if the root layout is a LinearLayout or android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" if you are using a relative layout

Comment: No more errors and the image appears in the layout.That is great.I somehow not able to get it down...But most of my questions were answererd....YOU ARE SUPERB!!!!

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath glad for you :D don't forget to accept the answer, also don't hesitate to answer question when you find some problems!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above I had to add "AttributeSet attr" parameter hence the game view constructor was named as

> public game(Context context,AttributeSet attr)

Now the view appears in XML layout.Placing it to the bottom is the next issue.